# How to Make an efficient connection between two interfaces (Using generics)?

Tags: java, generics, interface

first of all excuse me if this is a duplicate question.

I am writing a calculator for unlimited numbers.
since this is for unlimited number, i've decided to use a linked-list structure to store my numbers.

I wrote two interfaces: `Numbers` which stores numbers and `basicOperations` which is for operations.

i have two class: `Complex`  and  `Non_complex`, which implement Numbers.

the easiest way to connect `Numbers` and `basicOperations` is to implement `basicOperations` by `Complex` and `Non_Complex` and create instances and do the calculation, something like this:

```
interface basicOperations {

    String addition(Numbers anotherNumber);
    // other methods
}


interface Numbers {
    //some methods
}


public class Complex implements Numbers, basicOperations {

    /**
     * some codes . . .
     */

    String addition(Numbers anotherNumber) {
        Complex secondNumber = (Complex) anotherNumber;
        /**
         * do the calculation and return the result
         */
    }
}
```

the same will be for `Non_complex`.

and finally i will use a switch-case, specify the operation from input, create 2 instances of `Complex` or `Non_complex` and store entered numbers in them, and do the calculation.

somehow, i don't want to use this way. i wanna challenge myself more with more complicated (Better) ways. i've thought about some ways, one of them is this:

creating a class (assume its name is `connect`) and do the operations in it like this:

```
class connect {

    char currentOperation;

    void calculate(Numbers A, Numbers B) {
        if (currentOperation == '+') {
            addition.DoIt(A, B);
        }

        class addition implements calculate {

            static void <U extends Complex> DoIt(U num1, U num2) {
                System.out.println(num1.addition(num2));
            }

            static void <U extends non_Complex> DoIt(U num1, U num2) {
                System.out.println(num1.addition(num2));
            }

            static void <U extends Numbers> DoIt(U num1, U num2) {
                if (num1 instanceof Complex) {
                    Complex A = (Complex) num1;
                    Complex B = (Complex) num2;
                    System.out.println(A.addition(B));
                } else {
                    // the same codes like `if` will go for `Non-complex`.
                }
            }
        }
    }


interface calculate {

        static void <U extends Numbers> DoIt(U num1, U num2);
        static void <U extends Complex> DoIt(U num1, U num2);
        static void <U extends Non_complex> DoIt(U num1, U num2);


}
```

The other ways are similar like this way (using generics and connect two interfaces in a class and so on).

I'm new to generics and it's my first time to use multiple interfaces. i know there's a lot of ways, i'm looking for bests according to my program.

now, due to the question title, which way is more efficient, more optimized and better in every aspect?

and is my use of generics correct or i have to write it in another way?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Might be better suited for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Trying to do this sort of thing _in general_ is going to be...problematic.  You're almost certainly going to be better off picking *one* type and sticking to it -- maybe `Complex`.

Comment: Note that in `DoIt` I would just use `basicOperation` for the type of `num1` and `num2` unless you need to handle some other type of "num"

Comment: @LouisWasserman sry, i didn't get it, u meant it's better to remove `Non-complex` and work just with `complex` ?

Comment: @RC. `basicOperation` is an `interface`, how to use it in `DoIt` ?

Comment: @HMD yes, that's exactly what I mean.  Pick one and only one numeric type.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Multiplication, division and power are basically different for complex and non-complex numbers, even addition and subtraction is a little different cause for complex numbers we have 2 parts. doesn't it have much more effort to specify the type to perform operations?

Comment: @HMD the same way you do use Numbers, Complex etc

Comment: @RC. would you please give an example? i use `basicOperation` methods in `DoIt` which are all implemented by `Complex` or `Non_complex` classes. i can't figure it out how exactly to do it.

Comment: What do you mean, much more effort to specify the type?  All noncomplex numbers can be expressed as complex numbers with imaginary part 0.  Java's type system just really isn't very compatible with the kind of things you're trying to do here.

Comment: @LouisWasserman  i meant when for example i wanna do a multiplication, first i should specify whether it is non-complex or not, to use the specific code for it, i can't use the same multiplication code for both complex and non-complex number, even if the difference, as u mentioned, is just that in non-complex, complex part is 0. in fact i have to write two functions, one for complex and one for non-complex numbers. anyway, i'll think more about using one type.

Comment: *Why* do you have to write two functions?

Comment: @LouisWasserman aha!!! now i understand, tnx a lot.

Comment: @LouisWasserman suppose i do it with just one type, which way (according to the question and explanations) is better to do calculations?